# Codeigniter can't get a simple post data variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, controller

THIS IS FIXED, I had named my function the same name as my controller, changed function name from login to do_login, now works a treat, thanks all

Hi this should be really simple:-

Im writing a php site using CI

im trying to get a simple POST variable im my controler using:

```
public function login()
{
    $something = $this->input->post('something');
}
```

This on a controller name Login.php , the idea is have a form pass the POST data to this function at login/login, but I get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property:
>   Login::$input
>
> Filename: controllers/login.php
>
> Line Number: 38
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function post() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\rcity\application\controllers\login.php
>   on line 38

Ive tried get_instance(), but I can refer to everything else as `$this` inside the controller, as soon as I mention POST it dies, and off what ive read the input class is already loaded so thats not the issue, any ideas?

Thanks

HERES the full file for login.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array(
               'title' => '*** | Login',

                );
                $this->load->helper('login_helper');
                $this->load->view('head_view',$data);
                if (check_login()==TRUE){$this->load->view('header_logged_in');}
                else {$this->load->view('header_logged_out');}
                $this->load->view('nav_view');
                $this->load->view('login_view');
                $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }
        public function login()
        {
            $something = $this->input->post('something');
            $this->load->helper('login_helper');

        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the form's going via POST? Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` in your script to verify

Comment: Is this in a class? If so, which class are you extending?

Comment: Hi added the resto of the file im extending CI_Controller

Comment: And regardless of the form going via post or not the page wont load because of the error so the form could never even be submitted, thanks for any help mucho apreaciated

Comment: If it is fixed then please write an answer yourself, and subsequently accept that answer. This will help other users finding this question later.

Comment: I would but the site will not let me answer my own quastion as I dont have enough kudos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name your function the same as the controller... that would make it a constructor.

You're best best is to do this:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // the stuff you currently have in index()
}

public function index()
{
    $this->login_user();
}

public function login_user()
{
    // your code here
}
```